# I have a list of numbers and I want to know the first numbers that come and after a certain number

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following list as the following x=[4,6,8,10,12,13,14] and I want for example to know the index of the numbers 10 and 12 because they came before and after 11

Comment: Do you want to find the largest number that's smaller than 11 and the smallest that's larger from the list, or do you want to find the numbers at the indices adjacent to where 11 would go in the (sorted?) list?

Comment: Are your lists always sorted?

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you give a try to a *good old loop* ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering list `x` is sorted, you may use the [**bisect**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to achieve what you wish in the fastest way possible.

For example:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> x = [4,6,8,10,12,13,14]
>>> bisect.bisect_left(x, 11)
4
>>> x[4]
12
```

The bisect module works by implementing a basic binary search on top of a sorted list.

You may either use [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) or [`bisect.bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right).

Left will cause you to get the left-most index in case of duplicate entries, while right (or without any specification) will return the right-most insertion point:

```
>>> x = [1,2,2,3]
>>> bisect.bisect(x, 2)
3
>>> bisect.bisect_left(x, 2)
1
```

Comment: Link only answer. Please detail with examples. (not my downvote)

Comment: Yes, maybe... can you explain what `bissect_left` and `bissect_right` do? Imagine the link is broken and the lazy dev doesn't want to google for that/every python docs are gone

Comment: Don't tell it to anyone please, I try to be an *sshole as much as possible

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[4,6,8,10,12,13,14]
given_val = 11
after_val_ix = x.index(min([r for r in x if r > given_val]))
before_val = x.index(max([r for r in x if r < given_val]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A different version of @naivepredictor's answer:

```
from operator import itemgetter

x = [4,6,8,10,12,13,14]
given_val = 11
after_val = min([(i, n) for i, n in enumerate(x) if n > given_val], key=itemgetter(1))
before_val = max([(i, n) for i, n in enumerate(x) if n < given_val], key=itemgetter(1))

print(after_val)  # (4, 12)
print(before_val) # (3, 10)
```